# Symfony2 - Redirect a route to an external URL

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have this route in the local project:

```
/test/test2.php?param1=a&param2=b....
```

I would like to redirect it to an external URL:

```
http://test.com/test/test2.php?param1=a&param2=b....
```

How to do it using Symfony?

I was trying to use the routing directly without a Controller

```
test:
path: /test/{rest}
defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirectUrl
    path: http://test.com/{rest}
    permanent: true
```

But I am loosing the parameters: test2.php?param1=a&param2=b....

I was also trying to use the controller Action:

Routing:

```
test:
path: /test/{rest}
defaults:
    _controller: MyBundle:Default:test
```

Controller:

```
public function oaiAction($rest)
{
    return $this->redirect('http://test.com/'.$rest);
}
```

But I am loosing the parameters.

Any idea? I only need to change the local project base url to the remote one by keeping all the parameters.

Comment: Just get the request in the method. Then you will have access to all the parameters and you can redirect with those parameters.

Comment: @DipenShah, the problem is that the parameters can vary. Can I just get all the params and assign them to the new url?

Comment: Yes you can. You just need the query behind the request.

Comment: could you please post it as an answer with the details on how to do it?

Comment: Sure give me some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with a simple regex:

```
public function testAction()
{       
    $route = $this->getRequest()->get('_route');
    $url = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
    $url = preg_replace('/^(.*?)\/test/i', 'http://test.com/test', $url);

    return $this->redirect($url, 301);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, do this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function oaiAction(Request $request, $rest)
    {
        $parameters = http_build_query($request->query->all());
        return $this->redirect('http://stackoverflow.com/?'.$parameters);
    }
}
```

This will redirect with the parameters.

Comment: Thanks Dipen, but I did it with an regex, will post the answer. Of course, +1 for you.